# Limit length of line in standard draw

Tags: java, stddraw

I currently have a program with a grid and lines that will be drawn between dots in the grid. It uses standard draw. I wish to limit the length of the lines, so that they can only go from the adjacent points, but do not know how I would do this.

Thanks

```
StdDraw.setCanvasSize(400, 400);
StdDraw.setXscale(0, 10);
StdDraw.setYscale(0, 10);      

//dots
double radius = .15;
double spacing = 2.0;

for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
        StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.GRAY); 
        StdDraw.filledCircle(i * spacing, j * spacing, radius );
    }
}
StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLUE); 
StdDraw.text(0, 9.5, player1_name);
StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.RED); 
StdDraw.text(5, 9.5, player2_name);
int turn = 1;
     for (int i = 0; i <= 40; i++) { 
         if (turn % 2 == 0)
           StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.RED);
         else
           StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLUE);

         while(!StdDraw.mousePressed()) { }
         double x = StdDraw.mouseX();
         double y = StdDraw.mouseY();
   System.out.println(x + " " + y);
         StdDraw.setPenRadius(.01);
         StdDraw.show(200); 
               while(!StdDraw.mousePressed()) { }
               double x2 = StdDraw.mouseX();
               double y2 = StdDraw.mouseY();
               StdDraw.show(200); 
double xround = Math.round(x); 
double yround = Math.round(y);
double x2round = Math.round(x2);
double y2round = Math.round(y2);
  int xroundb = (int) xround; 
  int yroundb = (int) yround;
  int x2roundb = (int) x2round;
  int y2roundb = (int) y2round;
StdDraw.line(xround, yround, x2round, y2round);
System.out.println("Line Drawn"); 
StdDraw.show();
```

Comment: @RohitJain  My experience is that when code is broken, people rarely know which part is relevant.  That is why I commonly suggest:  "For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)."

Answer (score 1):

Ah I get it.  You are not asking about the actual `line` method which does work correctly, you want logic such that `line` is not called if adjacent dots are not selected.

Well, first we need to know which adjacent connections are allowed.  That is can we have Vertical?  Horizontal? Diagonal?  I will explain each just in case

So you have `spacing = 2.0`.  Well, that should be sufficient to check for adjacency.

```
if (Math.abs(x2round - xround) > spacing) {
   // don't draw
} else if (Math.abs(y2round - yround) > spacing)) {
   // don't draw
} else if (Math.abs(y2round - yround) > 0.0) && Math.abs(x2round - xround) > 0.0) {
   // don't draw if diagonal connections are forbidden
   // if diagonal is allowed, remove this else if condition
} else {
   StdDraw.line(xround, yround, x2round, y2round);
}
```

So if you don't draw, then you have to enforce your game logic.  Perhaps the player forfeits a turn.  Perhaps the player is given another chance to select adjacent dots.  It is up to you.  It is always a bit crazy comparing doubles due to roundoff, so instead of using 0.0, you might want to choose a very small epsilon double value to make sure you catch all cases.